# Having trouble using index as my only URL using Php

Tags: php, nav

I'm learning and I need my index to run my pages instead of the links using php if statements and I'm missing something in my code. It just runs my header over and over again.

my if statements:

```
 <?php
if (!isset($_GET['page']))
 {
 require('index.php');
 }
 else if ($_GET['page'] == 'aboutus') {
     if (!isset($_GET['action'])) {
         require('aboutus.php');
     } else if ($_GET['action'] == 'store') {
         require('store.php');
     } else if ($_GET['action'] == 'contactus') {
         require('contactus.php');
     }
      else
    {
    require('index.php');
    }
 }
 else
    {
require('index_.php');
}
 ?>
```

My nav bar:

```
      <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="?page=index.php">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="?page=aboutus.php">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="?page=store.php">Current Items</a></li>
      <li><a href="?page=contactus.php">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I know I'm missing something, I'm just not sure what.

Comment: You're looking for pages without `.php` yet are including `.php` in the query params. Closing as typo.

Comment: you never set the param `action` could that be the problem?

Comment: First fix the `.php` part mentioned by script47, then add the action like `<li><a href="?page=aboutus&action=store">Current Items</a></li>`

Comment: It is unclear where the GET variable `action` comes into the picture - are there going t be urls like `?page=aboutus&action=store`? or is your logic above somewhat confused?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly that you wish to load a new file based upon the querystring parameter `page` ( it is unclear where the querystring parameter `action` comes from or how it is used ) then perhaps this might help.

```
<?php

    /* set a variable for the querystring parameter "page" */
    $page=isset( $_GET['page'] ) ? filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) : false;


    if( !$page ) $file='index';
    else {

        $pages=array(/* possible files to include */
            'aboutus','store','contactus'
        );

        /* ensure user supplied GET variable is in desired format */
        $page = strtolower( trim( pathinfo( $page, PATHINFO_FILENAME ) ) );

        /* Find page in array of pages - or use default "index" */
        if( in_array( $page, $pages ) )$file = $pages[ array_search( $page, $pages ) ];
        else $file = 'index';
    }

    require sprintf( '%s.php', $file );
?>
```

The above could be simplified slightly like so:

```
<?php
    /* set a variable for the querystring parameter "page" */
    $page=isset( $_GET['page'] ) ? filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) : false;

    $pages=array(/* possible files to include */
        'aboutus','store','contactus'
    );

    /* ensure user supplied GET variable is in desired format */
    $page = strtolower( trim( pathinfo( $page, PATHINFO_FILENAME ) ) );

    /* Find page in array of pages - or use default "index" */
    if( in_array( $page, $pages ) )$file = $pages[ array_search( $page, $pages ) ];
    else $file = 'index';

    require sprintf( '%s.php', $file );
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

why is that??? you can implement Single Page Application that url only change ater hashTag like :

```
link.url/index#about-us
link.url/index#store
and ...
```

about your problem , after require your code continueus , you must `die;` after each require to finish loop. just made it a little prettier.

```
 <?php
if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
    require('index.php');die;
}

if ($_GET['page'] != 'aboutus') {
    require('index_.php');die;
}

// where is your action variable in your code?????????????
// it's about us
if (!isset($_GET['action'])) {
    require('aboutus.php');die;
} 

switch ($_GET['action']) {
    case 'store':
        require('store.php');die;
        break;

    case 'contactus':
        require('contactus.php');die;
        break;

    default:
        die("route is not defined");
        break;
 }


 ?>
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem. This suggest doing something completely different which is not possible with `php`.

Comment: Your update will still not fix the actual issue and is completely wrong. There is no loop and `die` will not complete the loop, it kills the script.

Comment: what link do you click ? if it is about us , it is becouse there is no action outside of a form , you just passed page variable through your link ``` <li><a href="?page=aboutus.php">About</a></li>```